# PagedCollectionView not found in Silverlight 4 (again? yes)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, pagedcollectionview

I know this will sound quite redundant, but sadly, no answer I have found to this problem online helped me.

I am running Visual Studio 2010, and using the Silverlight 4 SDK (April 2011 version) for my project. (set in the properties, I double-checked)

I did add "using System.Windows.Data;" at the beginning of my .cs file.

Yet, the compiler still gives me "not found" errors concerning my calls to PagedCollectionView.

When I type "System.Windows.Data.", the completion gives me plenty of suggestions, but no "PagedCollectionView"... the first suggestion I get starting with P is "PropertyGroupDescription".

Has this useful tool just been erased out of the surface of the Earth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to assembly `System.Windows.Data` for [PagedCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The namespace `System.Windows.Data` is used in multiple assemblies for example `System.Windows` that contains `PropertyGroupDescription`